# Including ToC from second volume in first volume, and vice versa

Tags: table-of-contents

I am preparing a book which will be printed in two separate volumes, and I'd like to show in the ToC the full content in both, either in two separate ToCs (Index for Volume I / Index for Volume II), or as a single ToC where the volume number becomes an unnumbered part which contains chapters and sections for that book.

I have looked around, but I can't find an answer. I am using memoir if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 7):

This should work. Suppose the other volume is named `volumetwo` and the file `volumetwo.toc` already exists.

```
\makeatletter
\def\tableofcontentsfrom#1#2{
\section*{#2\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase#2}{\MakeUppercase#2}}%
\begingroup\makeatletter%
  \@input{#1.toc}%
\endgroup%
}
\makeatother

\tableofcontentsfrom{volumetwo}{Contents of Volume 2}
```

(It is a modification of original `\tablofcontents` and `\@starttoc` macros.)

**Automated variant with one long TOC for both volumes** (I just hadn't automated the choice of the top-level according to book/report/article class)

```
\makeatletter
\def\gentoc#1{
\section*{#1\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase#1}{\MakeUppercase#1}}%
\begingroup\makeatletter%
 \let\l@toplevel\l@part%    use for BOOK class
% \let\l@toplevel\l@chapter% use for REPORT class
% \let\l@toplevel\l@section% use for ARTICLE class
\let\l@part\l@chapter%
\let\l@chapter\l@section%
\let\l@section\l@subsection%
\let\l@subsection\l@subsubsection%
}
\def\endgentoc{%
\endgroup%
}
\def\gentocfile#1#2{\l@toplevel{#1}{0}\@input{#2.toc}}
\makeatother

...

\begin{gentoc}{Complete Table of Contents}
\gentocfile{First volume}{volumeone}
\gentocfile{Second volume}{volumetwo}
\end{gentoc}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try it in a couple of hours and report back.

Comment: Neat suggestion, though you may want to insert a `\makeatother` command following the `\endgroup` statement.

Comment: @Mico: Sorry, but I don't catch what you mean. The example I provided is fully operational.

Comment: @tohecz -- since rerunning volume 1 will recreate `volumeone.toc`, and similarly for volume 2, it's really safer after the "final run" of each to make a copy of the `.toc` file under another name that won't get wiped out by rerunning, and input that.  and remember that including the second t-of-c may result in changed page numbers, so getting to the "final" version is iterative.

Comment: @Mico -- in the example, `\makeatletter` is *after* `\begingroup`, so it will just disappear at the `\endgroup`.

Comment: @tohecz -- I erred. See Barbara Beeton's comment for why the additional `\makeatother` isn't needed.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: the file `volumetwo.toc` doesn't get wiped by running `latex volumeone` and vice versa. I removed the `\openout` command from my definition. I think that running latex 6 times (for v1, v2, v1, v2, v1, v2) should be enough to get the correct result.

Comment: @tohecz -- running latex three times each on both volumes should probably be good enough, as long as the contents for the other volume is included for the whole process.  you're correct about any run not obliterating the `.toc` file for the other volume; didn't mean to imply that it did.  but do check carefully if you've got any front matter following the t-of-c in *either* volume -- that's where the page numbers could change.  removing `\openout` limits your options if you have to make a last-minute change somewhere, or do a second edition; document carefully what you've done.

Comment: In the end I went with a slightly different approach: each volume will have its own detailed toc, but before that I will place a general toc that includes volume I/II as parts, and each book's chapters skipping sections, using a hand-edited file.  

    \makeatletter
    \def\pianoDellOpera#1{
    \section*{#1\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase#1}{\MakeUppercase#1}}%
    \begingroup\makeatletter%
        \@input{piano_dell_opera.toc}%
    \endgroup%
    }

It's exactly what I needed, thanks to everybody who contributed to this thread!

Comment: This seams interesting, let's make it automated ;) -- see the update of the answer.